# How to handle deferred installation

Tags: ios, mobile-safari, ios-universal-links, dynamic-links

We are currently exploring deferred installation using iOS universal links. Our web page includes universal links with specific user data that we want to pass to the app after first installation.

We are looking for suggestions on implementing a seamless transition from Safari to the app, where the device can be consistently and uniquely identified. Any insights or best practices regarding JavaScript-based fingerprinting, storing identifiers, and linking them to user accounts within the app would be greatly appreciated. Additionally, I'm interested in ensuring compliance with privacy regulations and maintaining transparent data collection practices. Thank you in advance